# Android google Ads alignment issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a google advertisement in my android app using com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView in my Xml file like below. After a while i have noticed that the ads go left and keeps spaces from right. I change the gravity to "center" and the layout_gravity to center but still the same
this is my xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_bar"
        layout="@layout/top_main_action_bar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9" >

        <include layout="@layout/channel_list_viewpager" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listOverflow"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/overflow_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/popup_menu_shadow"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="/7229/Assafir_Mobile_Apps" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: using this inside which layout? either Linear or Relative?

Comment: i change from SMART_BANNER to BANNER and its Work!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Gravity center will not work as you adview width and height is wrap content.

LayoutGravity "center" will only work if parent layout is Linear Layout.

You have to user horizontal center true if you parent layout is a Relative Layout and make sure that adView's parent layout is not wrap content.

You can do something like this - 


<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="/722569/ID" />
    </RelativeLayout>


Or 


 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="/722569/ID" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you are using BANNER, you can give height 50 dp hard coded as Banner size is 50 dp for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="/7229/Assafir_Mobile_Apps" />
```